# Postgres Sql Insertion using Begin Exception Block Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am working query which uses begin exception block it gives me syntax error near insert here is my query

```
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO public.role(
        id, "RoleName")
        VALUES (1, 'SomeRole')
        RETURNING id as roleid;
    
EXCEPTION
    RETURNING -1 as roleid
END
    
    select roleid
```

Comment: You cant use such code just in ```psql``` or ```pgadmin```, it can be run only inside ```PL/pgSQL``` function or ```DO``` operator. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING

Comment: FYI, Postgresql 9.4 is EOL by about a 6 month. See [Versions](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You might want to think about moving to a newer version. That will not change the error, per @ИгорьТыра's comment, but it will get you a version that gets bug and security fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in that situation several times. I usually do something like this:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() 
    RETURNS INT AS
    $$
    DECLARE
      some_var INT;
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO public.role(id, RoleName)
        VALUES(1, 'SomeRole') 
        RETURNING public.role.id INTO some_var;
        
        RETURN some_var;
        
         EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
         RETURN -1;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select * from test_function();
```

[Check the fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nhDmeRNgZ6f2L6sKky6HvV/1) to see what happens with and without exception.
Note: For some reason, in fiddle the $$ should be replaces by quotes, and therefore quotes inside are double quoted.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to do so using **PostgreSql**. You can user **Begin** with **Commit** only.

Here is the syntax you can follow on this

```
BEGIN;

        INSERT INTO public.role(
        id, "RoleName")
        VALUES (1, 'SomeRole')
        RETURNING id as roleid;
    
COMMIT;
```

Here **BEGIN** block will automatically rollback your transaction. You can return last inserted **roleid** as well by doing like this.

Comment: This answer shows pure SQL, which is barely related to the code in the question. Then again, the question isn't much of a *question* to begin with.